# Xcode segue works sometimes in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to pass a value to the next ControllerView but I am getting this error:

```
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

The error is telling me to use segue.destinationViewController.
However, segue.destinationViewController is non-existand. Only segue.destination exists.

ControllerView 1:

```
 class TechniqueListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var activeRow = 0



let cellContent = ["Stance", "Move Forward", "Move Backward", "Move Right", "Move Left", "Jab", "Cross", "Hook", "Uppercut", "Body Jab", "Body Cross", "Body Hook", "Body Uppercut", "Leg Kick", "Body Kick", "Switching Stances", "Switch Leg Kick", "Switch Body Kick", "Push Kick", "Switch Push Kick", "Front Push Kick", "Switch Front Push Kick", "Spinning Back Kick", "Knee", "Switch Knee", "Elbow", "Tornado Kick"]



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    //gets # of rows


    return cellContent.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
 //defines content of each cell

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TechniqueCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    activeRow = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier:  "IndividualTechniqueSe", sender:IndividualTechniqueController.self)     

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "IndividualTechniqueSe"{

        let TechniqueIntent = segue.destination as! IndividualTechniqueController
        TechniqueIntent.activeRow2 = activeRow
}


func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

}

ControllerView 2:

```
import UIKit

class IndividualTechniqueController: UIViewController {

var activeRow2 = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Whenever I build the app and tap on a row, it only goes to the desired ControllerView 10% of the time. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: `/ /MARK: - Navigation` is not an error.

Comment: why you use `activerow`? where is your IBOutlet of `tableView`? Do you need catch clicked index number on `destination view controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControllerView 1:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


            activeRow = indexPath.row
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("IndividualTechniqueSe", sender:nil)     

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

           if segue.identifier == "IndividualTechniqueSe"{

            let TechniqueIntent = segue.destinationViewController as! IndividualTechniqueController
            TechniqueIntent.activeRow2 = activeRow
           }
    }
```